# Apex - Displaying a list after deserialising json

Tags: json, salesforce, apex

I would like to make a http callout to import json and display the information in a visualforce page. The problem I'm having is that the json is nested and so I need to loop through the child nodes.

I have the following class derived using the json2apex application:

```
public class CHForm {

public class FilingHistoryItem {
    public String DocumentDate;
    public String FormType;
    public String DocumentCategory;
    public String Document;
    public String DocumentDescription;
  }

public FilingHistory FilingHistory;

public class FilingHistory{
    public List<FilingHistoryItem> FilingHistoryItem;
  }


public static CHForm parse(String json) {
    return (CHForm) System.JSON.deserialize(json, CHForm.class);
  }


}
```

In my controller class I can create a CHForm object (*reponseForm*) and deserialise the json into the *reponseForm* object using the following:

```
HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
String chFormJson = res.getBody();
responseForm  = CHForm.parse(chFormJson);
```

but how do I then display a list of all FilingHistoryItem in the visualforce page? Do I need to create a list object in my controller or is there a way of directly referencing the list from the visualforce page?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused by your apex, shouldn't it be :

```
public List<FilingHistoryItem> FilingHistory;

public class FilingHistoryItem {
    public String DocumentDate;
    public String FormType;
    public String DocumentCategory;
    public String Document;
    public String DocumentDescription;
  }
```

Then you'd be able to do:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!responseform.FilingHistory.}" var="item" id="theRepeat">
   <apex:outputText value="{! item.DocumentDate}" />  //etc
</apex:repeat
```

The way you've set it up now, I think it may work like this:

```
 <apex:repeat value="{!responseform.FilingHistory.FilingHistoryItem}" var="item" id="theRepeat">
       <apex:outputText value="{! item.DocumentDate}" />  //etc
    </apex:repeat
```

But it's a bit strange you name a list property as "...Item" and not "..Items", and nest so deeply, but maybe that's a json dependency.